# My SQL query involving multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables. First table stores id in multiple column whose value is stored in other table. I want a query that returns result which has structure of my 1st table but values from 2nd table. To be more specific let's say I have a table like this:

**Table A**:

```
        Uniqueid  song_1  song_2 song_3 song_4 song_5
           1        2       4     5        6      8
```

**Table B**:

```
                  song_id    song_name
                     1         abcd
                     2         def
                     3         efg
                     4         ghi
                     5         abdal
                     6         nsadln
                     7         knwldn
                     8         jdkabdb
```

I want to fetch data from Table A but it should look like:

Desired result:

```
        Uniqueid  song_1  song_2  song_3    song_4   song_5
           1       def      ghi   abdal      nsadln  jdkabdb
```

I have used join and making objects but no luck so far. Please help me out.

Comment: Nooooooooooooo. Normalise your schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a bunch of left joins to get to your answer:

```
SELECT
    a.UniqueId
    ,s1.song_name as song_1
    ,s2.song_name as song_2
    ,s3.song_name as song_3
    ,s4.song_name as song_4
    ,s5.song_name as song_5
FROM
    TableA a
    LEFT JOIN TableB s1
    ON a.song_1 = s1.song_id 
    LEFT JOIN TableB s2
    ON a.song_2 = s2.song_id
    LEFT JOIN TableB s3
    ON a.song_3 = s3.song_id 
    LEFT JOIN TableB s4
    ON a.song_4 = s4.song_id
    LEFT JOIN TableB s5
    ON a.song_5 = s5.song_id
```

Comment: Worked!! Thanks for the support.Didnt know can  use as to change coloumn name.

Comment: you don't actually have to put as you can just put the alias but I thought it would be a little clearer intention for you.  You are welcome.

Comment: Thanks once again.My sql query look like this     
**select a.Unique_id,b.sub_name as song_1,c.sub_name as song_2,d.sub_name as song_3,e.sub_name as song_4,f.sub_name as song_5,g.sub_name as song_6 from TableA a,TABLEB b,TABLEB c,TABLEB d,TABLEB e,TABLEB f,TABLEB g where b.song_id =a.song_1 and c.song_id =a.song_2 and d.song_id =a.song_3 and e.song_id =a.song_4 and f.song_id =a.song_5 and g.song_id =a.song_6**

Comment: The only thing about using the implicit join syntax you are using it will treat everything like an inner join which will be a problem is one of the columns in tablea is null or doesn't match Tableb.  Using Explicit Join Syntax should always be done, and in this case a left join would probably be safest.